# Changing HamburgerMenuControl.Content from a view inside Mahapps Hamburger Menu Control

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro

I have a HamburgerMenuControl with some views inside it and it's working fine.

Now I would like to implement a button inside one of the views so once the user clicks on the button, it displays another view.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85trP.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a few hours studying the examples available on MahApps repository I figured out a solution using a static method inside a class to control the navigation.

Here's an example https://github.com/thyagocampos/wpf_tests